# Express.JS: Logout without destroying the session

Tags: node.js, session, express

I have an Express.js application and I would like to keep a log of all the sessions by the users. This has created a bit of trouble while implementing the Logout feature. The accepted practice is to use `session.destroy` but I do not want to do this since it deletes the session from the database. Is it possible to expire the session without destroying it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use some key in the session. For example:

```
req.session.date = "...";
```

Comment: I was hoping to use some of the 'expires' params already being saved in the database. That can help serve 2 purposes. If I just save a date, the date can tell me when the user logged out.

Comment: Ok, what if you set *req.session.date = '...'* and check this parameter once the user lands on the page.

Comment: It seems that that is the only option. Doesn't look like I can use the expires date already in the database. I will try another time today. (If you edit your answer with `req.session.date` I'll mark as correct :) )